# Why does ivy 1.13.0 from GNU ELPA have counsel included?

Tags: ivy, counsel

MELPA has a package called *counsel*. Most guides on the *ivy* package recommend installing *counsel* as well. GNU ELPA doesn't have *counsel*. Why doesn't it?

I've installed *ivy 0.13.0* from GNU ELPA. I don't have *counsel* listed among installed packages and I don't have a directory called *counsel* in *~/.emacs.d/elpa*. However, I have commands *counsel-mode*, *counsel-find-file*, and other commands which start with *counsel-*, and they work. Why do I have them?

Why does MELPA have a separate package called *counsel*?

---

Edit: Comparing the `ivy` package from GNU ELPA and MELPA:

- Filenames in common:

  ```
  colir.el
  dir
  ivy-autoloads.el
  ivy-overlay.el
  ivy-pkg.el
  ivy.el
  ivy.info
  ```
- Only in GNU ELPA ivy-0.13.0:

  ```
  ChangeLog
  counsel.el
  ivy-hydra.el
  swiper.el
  ```
- Only in MELPA ivy-20200601.1105:

  ```
  elpa.el
  ivy-avy.el
  ivy-faces.el
  ivy-help.org
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked a similar question some years ago, it appears to be the byproduct of a rename: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/915#issuecomment-286198927. To quote the relevant part:

> Oh yea. By popular demand, swiper 0.7.0 -> ivy 0.8.0. On ELPA, ivy 0.8.0 bundles ivy, swiper and counsel. On MELPA, they are separate.